# Angular JS and Complex Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is an AngularJS widget which replaces a tag with an editable text field.  Clicking the text replaces it with an input field, and hitting enter on the input updates an existing resource.

I am not happy with the code I produced.  Are all of these evals and applys really necessary?  How can I improve this?

To use

```
editable-text(model="activeCustomer.phone_number", resource="Customer", field="phone_number")
```

The Directive Code

```
.directive("editableText", function($injector){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: document.views.directivePartials.editableText,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      $(elem).find(".noEdit").click(function(){
        scope.showEdit = true;
        scope.$apply();
      });

      var ENTER = 13;
      $(elem).find('.edit').keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == ENTER){
          var resource = $injector.get(attrs.resource);

          var params = {};
          params[attrs.field] = scope.value
          resource.update(params);
          scope.showEdit=false;
        }
      });

      scope.showEdit = false;
      scope.$watch(attrs.model, function(){
        scope.value = scope.$eval(attrs.model);
      });
    },
  };
})
```

The Template

```
span.editableTextField
input.edit(type="text", ng-show="showEdit", ng-model="value")
span.noEdit(ng-show="!showEdit") {{value}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not using jQuery with Angular, especially as you're learning.  None of what you're doing requires it.

1. You can get rid of the first use of `click` callback by using `ngClick` in your template:

   ```
   <span class="editableTextField" ng-click="showEdit = true">
   ```
2. You can get rid of the `keyup` callback buy using Angular-UI:

   ```
   <input class="edit" ... ui-keypress="{enter: 'handleEnter()'}">
   ```
3. I'd recommend using a two-way binding so you can write data back to the scope properly.
4. When you wire up `$watch`, you get the new value as the first argument.  That will save you another `$eval`.

Here's a fiddle for you... http://jsfiddle.net/maU9t/

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/pvtpenguin/25cqs/17**

Changes:

1. Create an `on-enter` directive that the `editable-text` directive uses in the template. The new `on-enter` directive can be reused anywhere.

   ```
   <input ... on-enter="update()" ... />
   ```
2. Use the `ng-click` directive to toggle `showEdit` state instead of relying on jquery and a function.

   ```
   <input ... on-click="showEdit = true" ... />
   ```
3. Binds `value` on the directive's isolate scope to the value of the directive's model attribute. This lets us remove the `scope.$watch` and creates a two-way binding between the local `value` and `activeCustomer.phone_number`

   ```
   <editable-text model="activeCustomer.phone_number"></editable-text>
   <input ... ng-model="value" />
   <span>{{value}}</span>

   ...

   scope: { 
       // give `value` and `activeCustomer.phone_number two-way binding
       value: '=model' 
   }
   ```

These changes completely remove the jQuery dependency.  Resulting directive:

```
myApp.directive("editableText", function($injector){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { 
        value: '=model' // Bind `value` to what is declared on the `model` attribute
    },
    templateUrl: "/tpl.html",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      scope.update = function() {
          var resource = $injector.get(attrs.resource);
          var params = {};
          params[attrs.field] = scope.value;
          resource.update(params);
          scope.showEdit=false;
      };
      scope.showEdit = false;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one version of inline editor. http://jsfiddle.net/pUMer/

Key features:

- Configure the initial mode of the inline editor
- Seperate scope for each inline editor, so that it wont interfere with
  the parent scope
- View the model of all the inline editors

If you want only on inline editor, pls. reduce the array element to size of one.

**HTML**:

```
<inline-editor inline-editor-mdl="inlineEditor"></inline-editor>
```