# Pro/con of using Angular directives for complex form validation/ GUI manipulation

Tags: angularjs

I am building a new SPA front end to replace an existing enterprise's legacy hodgepodge of systems that are outdated and in need of updating. I am new to angular, and wanted to see if the community could give me some perspective. I'll state my problem, and then ask my question.

I have to generate several series of check boxes based on data from a `.js` include, with data like this:

```
$scope.fieldMappings.investmentObjectiveMap = [
  {'id':"CAPITAL PRESERVATION", 'name':"Capital Preservation"},
  {'id':"STABLE", 'name':"Moderate"},
  {'id':"BALANCED", 'name':"Moderate Growth"},
   // etc
  {'id':"NONE", 'name':"None"}
];
```

The checkboxes are created using an `ng-repeat`, like this:

```
    <div ng-repeat="investmentObjective in fieldMappings.investmentObjectiveMap">
     ...
    </div>
```

However, I needed the values represented by the checkboxes to map to a different model (not just 2-way-bound to the fieldmappings object). To accomplish this, I created a directive, which accepts a destination array `destarray` which is eventually mapped to the model. I also know I need to handle some very specific gui controls, such as unchecking "None" if anything else gets checked, or checking "None" if everything else gets unchecked. Also, "None" won't be an option in every group of checkboxes, so the directive needs to be generic enough to accept a validation function that can fiddle with the `checked` state of the checkbox group's inputs based on what's already clicked, but smart enough not to break if there is no option called `"NONE"`. I started to do that by adding an ng-click which invoked a function in the controller, but in looking around stack overflow, I read people saying that its bad to put DOM manipulation code inside your controller - it should go in directives. So do I need *another* directive?

So far:
(html):

```
      <input my-checkbox-group
              type="checkbox"
              fieldobj="investmentObjective"
              ng-click="validationfunc()"
              validationfunc="clearOnNone()"
              destarray="investor.investmentObjective" />
```

Directive code:

```
.directive("myCheckboxGroup", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      destarray:      "=",  // the source of all the checkbox values
      fieldobj:       "=",  // the array the values came from
      validationfunc: "&"   // the function to be called for validation (optional)
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (scope.destarray.indexOf(scope.fieldobj.id) !== -1) {
        elem[0].checked = true;
      }
      elem.bind('click', function () {
        var index = scope.destarray.indexOf(scope.fieldobj.id);
        if (elem[0].checked) {
          if (index === -1) {
            scope.destarray.push(scope.fieldobj.id);
          }
        }
        else {
          if (index !== -1) {
            scope.destarray.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

.js controller snippet:

```
.controller( 'SuitabilityCtrl', ['$scope', function ( $scope ) {
  $scope.clearOnNone = function() {
    // naughty jQuery DOM manipulation code that
    // looks at checkboxes and checks/unchecks as needed
  };
```

The above code is done and works fine, except the naughty jquery code in `clearOnNone()`, which is why I wrote this question.

And here is my question: after ALL this, I think to myself - I could be done already if I just manually handled all this GUI logic and validation junk with jQuery written in my controller. At what point does it become foolish to write these complicated directives that future developers will have to puzzle over more than if I had just written jQuery code that 99% of us would understand with a glance? How do other developers draw the line?

I see this all over stack overflow. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425012/angular-js-and-complex-directives) seems like it could be answered with a dozen lines of straightforward jQuery, yet he has opted to do it the angular way, with a directive and a partial... it seems like a lot of work for a simple problem.

I don't want this question to violate the rules, so specifically, I suppose I would like to know: how *SHOULD* I be writing the code that checks whether "None" has been selected (if it exists as an option in this group of checkboxes), and then check/uncheck the other boxes accordingly? A more complex directive? I can't believe I'm the only developer that is having to implement code that is more complex than needed just to satisfy an opinionated framework. Is there another util library I need to be using?

Comment: +1: Gosh, what a great question. Unfortunately, it's too broad for Stackoverflow. This would be much better suited for Programmers.StackExchange.com. // P.S. I think many AngularJS developers are wrestling with similar difficulties/trade offs.

Comment: Just curious, is your username a tribute to the manufacturer of R.B.I. Baseball? http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.B.I._Baseball

Comment: Does your controller have direct access to the arrays that are backing the form? In that case you should just manipulate those directly rather than using JQuery to manipulate the DOM. I can't tell if it is going to be a problem for you here, but functions attached to $scope can easily be run multiple times during a $digest-loop and if you're doing DOM stuff in them it can be a serious performance-hit.

Comment: @JimG. heh, no, its a reference to the center square on a Go board. :) I'll try it over at Programmers Stack Exchange... thanks!

Comment: @ivarni I can access the array from the controller, but I still have to have screen elements respond to user events, which AFAIK, requires some deliberate consideration a-la jQuery, directives, vanilla JS, etc. Hence where to draw the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this on Programmers.StackExchange.com as per Jim's suggestion. In the meantime, I settled on a solution for handling all the tricky DOM manipulations.

I tried it both ways - handling the DOM event in the controller, and handling it via a directive:

(Via Controller) - .js code:

```
 $scope.clearOnNone = function(groupName, $event) {
    var chkboxArr = $('input[name^=' + groupName + ']'),
        nonNoneValChecked = false,
        targetElem = null,
        labelText = "";

    // get the target of the click event by looking at the <label> sibling's text
    targetElem = event.target.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim();

    // if target was the None option, uncheck all others
    if (targetElem === "None") {
      chkboxArr.each(function() {
        labelText = this.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim();

        if (labelText !== "None") {
          this.checked = false;
        }
      });
    }
    // if the target was anything BUT the None option, uncheck None
    else {
      chkboxArr.each(function() {
        labelText = this.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim();

        if (labelText === "None") {
          this.checked = false;
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

(Via Controller) - html code:

```
      <div ng-repeat="investmentObjective in fieldMappings.secondaryInvestmentObjectiveMap">
        <input checkbox-group
                type="checkbox"
                name="secondaryInvestmentObjective"
                ng-click="validationfunc('secondaryInvestmentObjective', $event)"
                validationfunc="clearOnNone('secondaryInvestmentObjective', $event)"
                fieldobj="investmentObjective"
                destarray="suitabilityHolder.suitability.secondaryInvestmentObjective" />
        <label class="checkbox-label"
                popover-title="{{investmentObjective.name}}"
                popover="{{investmentObjective.help}}"
                popover-trigger="mouseenter">{{investmentObjective.name}}
        </label>
      </div>
```

(Via Controller) - directive code:

```
.directive("checkboxGroup", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      destarray:      "=",  // the source of all the checkbox values
      fieldobj:       "=",  // the array the values came from
      validationfunc: "&"   // the function to be called for validation (optional)
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (scope.destarray.indexOf(scope.fieldobj.id) !== -1) {
        elem[0].checked = true;
      }
      elem.bind('click', function () {
        var index = scope.destarray.indexOf(scope.fieldobj.id);
        if (elem[0].checked) {
          if (index === -1) {
            scope.destarray.push(scope.fieldobj.id);
          }
        }
        else {
          if (index !== -1) {
            scope.destarray.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

I then decided that I hated the `event.target.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim()` lines... I feel like I should be double checking that all of those methods exist, or using a `try/catch`. So I rewrote the directive to include the logic from the controller:

(via directive) - html code:

```
      <div ng-repeat="otherInvestment in fieldMappings.otherInvestmentsMap">
        <input type="checkbox"
                checkbox-group
                groupname="otherInvestment"
                labelvalue="{{otherInvestment.name}}"
                fieldobj="otherInvestment"
                destarray="suitabilityHolder.suitability.otherInvestment" />
        <label class="checkbox-label"
                popover-title="{{otherInvestment.name}}"
                popover="{{otherInvestment.help}}"
                popover-trigger="mouseenter">{{otherInvestment.name}}
        </label>
      </div>
```

(via directive) - directive code:

```
.directive("checkboxGroup", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      destarray:      "=",  // the source of all the checkbox values
      fieldobj:       "=",  // the array the values came from
      groupname:      "@",  // the logical name of the group of checkboxes
      labelvalue:     "@"   // the value that corresponds to this checkbox
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      // Determine initial checked boxes
      // if the fieldobj.id exists in the destarray, check this checkbox
      if (scope.destarray.indexOf(scope.fieldobj.id) !== -1) {
        elem[0].checked = true;
      }

      // Update array on click
      elem.bind('click', function () {
        // store the index where the fieldobj.id exists in the destarray
        var index = scope.destarray.indexOf(scope.fieldobj.id),
            // get the array of checkboxes that form this checkbox group
            chkboxArr = $('input[groupname^=' + scope.groupname + ']');

        // Add if checked
        if (elem[0].checked) {
          if (scope.labelvalue === "None") {
            // loop through checkboxes and uncheck all the ones that are not "None"
            chkboxArr.each(function() {
              // have to noodle through the checkbox DOM element to get at its attribute list
              // - is there a cleaner way?
              var tmpLabelValue = this.attributes.labelvalue.nodeValue.trim();
              if (tmpLabelValue !== "None") {
                this.checked = false;
              }
            });
          }
          // if the target was anything BUT the None option, uncheck None
          else {
            chkboxArr.each(function() {
              var tmpLabelValue = this.attributes.labelvalue.nodeValue.trim();

              if (tmpLabelValue === "None") {
                this.checked = false;
              }
            });
          }

          if (index === -1) {
            // add the id to the end of the dest array
            // **will not maintain original order if several are unchecked then rechecked**
            scope.destarray.push(scope.fieldobj.id);
          }
        }

        // Remove if unchecked
        else {
          if (index !== -1) {
            scope.destarray.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

In retrospect, I suppose I prefer to house all the code in a directive, even though I think it's less intuitive and more complex than tossing all the handling in the controller via jQuery. It cuts out the clearOnNone() function from the controller, meaning that all the code that deals with this functionality it in the html markup and the directive.

I am not a fan of code like `this.attributes.labelvalue.nodeValue.trim()`, which I still ended up with in my directive. For scenarios like mine, where the business unit has certain requirements that (no other way to put it) are tedious and cumbersome, I don't know that there is really a 'clean' way to code it all up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to AngularJS but I this case I think I would solve it by using either an `ng-click` handler or `$scope.$watch` to update the state of the `NONE` model whenever the other models change.

## Using ng-click

I've whipped up a jsFiddle that shows how it could work with `ng-click`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dzj6K/1/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="objective in objectives">
        <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="objective.selected" ng-click="click(objective)" /> {{objective.name}}</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function myCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.objectives = [
        {'id':"CAPITAL PRESERVATION", 'name':"Capital Preservation"},
        {'id':"STABLE", 'name':"Moderate"},
        {'id':"BALANCED", 'name':"Moderate Growth"},
        {'id':"NONE", 'name':"None"}
    ];

    $scope.click = function(objective) {
        if (objective.id === "NONE") {
            if (objective.selected) {
                angular.forEach($scope.objectives, function(objective) {
                    if (objective.id !== "NONE") {
                        objective.selected = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            angular.forEach($scope.objectives, function(objective) {
                if (objective.id === "NONE") {
                    objective.selected = false;
                }
            });
        }
    };

}
```

## Using $scope.$watch

And a version of the jsFiddle that shows how it could work with `$scope.$watch`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dzj6K/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="objective in objectives">
        <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="objective.selected" /> {{objective.name}}</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function myCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.objectives = [
        {'id':"CAPITAL PRESERVATION", 'name':"Capital Preservation"},
        {'id':"STABLE", 'name':"Moderate"},
        {'id':"BALANCED", 'name':"Moderate Growth"},
        {'id':"NONE", 'name':"None"}
    ];

    $scope.$watch('objectives', function() {
        var anySelected = false;
        var noneModel = null;

        angular.forEach($scope.objectives, function(objective) {
            if (objective.id === "NONE") {
                noneModel = objective;
            } else {
                anySelected = anySelected || objective.selected;
            }
        });

        if (noneModel) {
            noneModel.selected = !anySelected;
        }

    }, true);

}
```

Comment: Interesting idea Karl. My main reservation about this approach for my scenario is that I have several groups of checkboxes, and I don't know that I want to set up a `$watch` for each one in the controller. I wonder about performance, since checking/unchecking boxes may fire additional `$watch` executions. The fiddle didn't work for me ('None' would never check). :(

Comment: @tengen I've updated my answer with an `ng-click` based approach, which is much more inline with what you are doing in your answer. I've done this mostly for completeness sake as you already have an answer that work for you which is great!

Comment: Decorating the objectives map with user selection is pretty clever. I had not considered it - I was only thinking of mapping to the final user object model that I want to submit. Its an extra step (to then interrogate the map and update the user model accordingly) but it could be handy in certain situations. Thanks for the great idea, and taking the time to help me out.